# How to fix an HTML element to his initial position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In an HTML page I have a search bar and at keyup event an unordered list is added after the search bar. Now, I want the results to cover the elements that are under the bar, so they should stay in the same position and not go down. What is the best way to achieve this?

[Image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB6M0.png)
[Image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DgyG.png)

The first is the template without text input, the second is the same template with input. The text input cause an ajax query to the server that responds with data that are used to construct a list. I want that this list does cover the content under the bar (Last five comments and others in this case)

I want a google.com behaviour (the bottoms after the search bar are covered by the results of the query)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always add the relevant code to your question so that we can see precisely what you are doing and my accurate suggestions. As it is now, the scenario is described so vaguely that we really couldn't do more than guess.

Comment: thanks for adding the details

Answer (score 1):

To keep the stuff below from moving, you'll need to remove your search suggestions from the layout flow. You can use the `position` CSS attribute to do this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

Specifically, try `position: absolute`: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position

> Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow.

That means the elements that are normally under the bar will still be laid out directly under the bar, without now making room for the added search suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to guest I solved the problem

Ancestor div

```
.w3-panel{
  position: relative;
}
```

Comments Div

```
#commentsDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

So the commentsDiv div will be positioned with respect to the w3-panel parent div and won't move to another position. Obviously the requested behaviour was to overlap the commentsDiv div and the resultsDiv so I've added

```
z-index: -1;
```

to indicate what div should be hidden in favour of the other (in this case commentsDiv div will be hide becouse it has a lower z-index (0 default)